# Angular Testing using karma: Electron browser times out

Tags: angularjs, angular

We are building an electron app using Angular 4. Most of the times, when I run the tests, I get the following error:

```
Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
Electron 1.7.9 (Node 7.9.0) ERROR
     Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms
```

This is the karma.conf:

```
const autowatched = process.env.npm_lifecycle_script.indexOf('--auto-watch') !== -1;

module.exports = function (config) {
  var grep = require('karma-webpack-grep');
  var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js')({ env: 'test' });
  var electronflags = autowatched ? ['--show'] : []; 

  testWebpackConfig.plugins = (testWebpackConfig.plugins || []).concat(grep({
   grep: config.grep,
   basePath: '', // same as basePath
   testContext: '../src' // same as require.context line in spec-bundle.js
  }));

  var configuration = {
   basePath: '',
   frameworks: ['jasmine'],
   exclude: [],

   client: {
     captureConsole: autowatched ? true : false,
     useIframe: false
   },
  files: [
  { pattern: './config/spec-bundle.js', watched: false },
  { pattern: './src/assets/**/*', watched: false, included: false, served: true, nocache: false }
  ],
  proxies: {
    "/assets/": "/base/src/assets/"
  },

preprocessors: { './config/spec-bundle.js': autowatched ? ['webpack', 'electron', 'sourcemap'] : ['coverage', 'webpack', 'electron', 'sourcemap'] },
webpack: testWebpackConfig,

webpackMiddleware: {
  noInfo: true,
  stats: {
    chunks: false
  }
},

reporters: ['mocha'],
port: 9876,
colors: true,
logLevel: autowatched ? config.LOG_INFO : config.LOG_WARN,

autoWatch: false,

browsers: ['ElectronDebugging'],
customLaunchers: {
  ElectronDebugging: {
    base: 'Electron',
    flags: electronflags
    ,
  },
 },

 singleRun: true
};

if (!autowatched) {
configuration.reporters.push('coverage');
configuration.coverageReporter = {
  type: 'in-memory'
};
configuration.reporters.push('remap-coverage');
configuration.remapCoverageReporter = {
  'text-summary': null,
  json: './coverage/coverage.json',
  html: './coverage/html'
};
} else {
// show console.log messages when debugging
configuration.browserConsoleLogOptions = {
  level: 'log',
  terminal: true
};
}

config.set(configuration);
};
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I ran into the same issue.

Comment: the issue was with the yarn version I had. The packages were not installed properly